# wrong top statement declaration in scala IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have the following warning, could you explain what does it mean, and how I can correct the code to get rid of the warning?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You forgot the return type in your method definition. Therefore the body is not well parsed.

For example:

```
def scaleMap(file: File, key: String): Map[String Int] = { ... }
```

If you don't know the correct return type immediately, you can just ignore the `return` part of the method definition. The return type will then be inferred by the compiler.

```
def scaleMap(file: File, key: String) = { ... }
```